# WooCommerce FlexSlider makes product images full size (1200 x 1200)

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, flexslider

I want to remove FlexSlider from my WordPress WooTheme (Astrum) since it looks terrible. It makes our images full-size, so our images look silly.

I would prefer to have a thumbnail gallery where you can click on an image and it becomes 400px x 400px or something more standard; can anyone help me with removing flexslider and replacing with a gallery?

http://dv8sports.inpresence.us/product/bag-1/ for example

Answer (score 0):

Flex slider is responsive. That means if you wrap slider inside some container it will stretch.

I would try to wrap the slider inside some other container which defines the preferred width. Your theme supports column shortcodes - use that.

According to their documentation, you can do something like:

```
[column width="one-third" place="first" ][/column]
[column width="one-third" place="first" ] Slider shortcode here [/column]
[column width="one-third" place="last" ][/column]
```

**Another point:** You submitted link to a product page and that page expects to contain product description and other stuff / not just a single image. Once you build the product page properly (add content) your image size will shrink according to surrounding content.

Hopefully this helps.